# gravity="bottom" in layer list not worked

Tags: xml, layer-list

I want to make a drawable that has two layer, rectangle and a line at bottom of rectangle.

be attention:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

but `android:gravity="bottom"` not working and second layer centered in parent.

[image: shot]

how can I fixed second layer at bottom of layer-list?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes. check my below answer. @ban-geoengineering

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not correct answer, because it seems be a bug!

but I got the desired result.

I change  above code to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:top="-5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks. So, you're drawing the top and sides of the rectangle out-of-view so that just the bottom line of the rectangle is shown at the required height?

Comment: Exactly! @ban-geoengineering